# Documenting solutions implemented in a software project

Tags: web-apps, software-development, archiving, knowledge-organization, knowledge-base

As a software developer I get stuck while implementing a feature and then I solve it somehow through lots of search, article reading, tutorials, etc.

But I would prefer a Web app (e.g. a central repository) that has a *workflow* defined in it that will allow me to *store/document* this kind of solutions to certain problems in a software project. So that I can search and refer the repo again in future to recall how I solved a problem if I encounter it again.

Blogging helps but some programming problems are very small and becomes very trivial for a blog post. On the other hand, can't describe a whole technical solution on issue trackers.

Please suggest if there is any Web app like that out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have finally decided to settle for **Git** and **Markdown**. For Git hosting I chose [GitLab](http://www.gitlab.com) because it is basically GitHub with addition of *free private repos*. The idea is to have a single repo for all logs and then have a single dir for each log or entry:

```
-root
  -Entry1
     Entry1.md
     file1.js
  -Entry2
     Entry2.md
     Entry2.html
```

I also plan to leverage *relative linking* and *line range highlighting* to reference code files within an entry dir or across the whole repo.

Maybe I can even make a repo for my blog someday.

Answer (score 2):

I’m using a **wiki** for a similar use case.

The good thing: You can build the site architecture/organization/navigation yourself.
The bad thing: You have to build the site architecture/organization/navigation yourself.

Almost any wiki should be suitable for your case, but it’s worth looking into details you care about.

Wikipedia has a [list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_wiki_software) and [comparison](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_wiki_software) of wiki software. The site [wikimatrix.org](http://www.wikimatrix.org/) allows to compare wikis based on selected features/requirements.

Don’t underestimate the look and feel. For such a wiki to really make sense, you should visit and edit it often. But if editing is no fun (i.e., not easy/quick, ugly, bad usability) for you, you might defer it or stop after the first few days of enthusiasm.

Personally, I’m using [**WikkaWiki**](http://www.wikkawiki.org/) (<s>daily</s> hourly for several years, have created around 2000 pages with more than 35000 edits):

- FLOSS.
- PHP, MySQL.
- Fast, little cruft.
- Comes with [syntax](http://docs.wikkawiki.org/SyntaxHighlighter) for code blocks (`%% your code here %%`) and supports syntax highlighting (`%%(php) your PHP code here %%`). You can even specify a file name (which also allows to download the code file) and starting line numbers (`%%(php;15;test.php) your "test.php" here, starting from line 15 %%`).
- Its default editor supports <kbd>Tab</kbd> (if you like to indent code that way).
- Because the URLs are "beautiful", you’ll be able to directly enter the URLs of pages you want to visit/edit (which saves a lot of time, thanks to browser’s autocomplete):
  `http://example.com/PHP`
  `http://example.com/PHP/edit`

Possible drawbacks: rather slow developing process (which is good for me, as long as the project is not dead); no full Unicode support (the next version, 1.4, will switch to full UTF-8; but almost everything should work just fine even now).

[**DokuWiki**](https://www.dokuwiki.org/) is another nice wiki. It’s also FLOSS, uses PHP, but it doesn’t require a database (saves all wiki pages in text files).